# Managed package upgrade

Tags: managed-package

I have created managed package and install my app all is good.
Now I have updated my app and created my new version and when I tried to install on the same org I get the message that I need to uninstall the old app

My question, what do I need to do in the package so that it’s easily be upgradable without uninstalling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package must be uploaded as Released, not Beta. Beta packages cannot be installed in production orgs and cannot be upgraded. Use Beta versions only for testing.

Comment: do you have a link where it talks about can you share

Comment: @NickKahn There's a few, maybe start [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=determine_managed_package_state.htm&type=5) or [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000325234&type=1&mode=1).